# Freemarker nested list in Liferay

Tags: json, liferay, freemarker

I'm trying to create some JSON in Liferay using templates and freemarker.
if I have one single #list it all seems ok, if I try to nest lists this way, it breaks with a general Liferay error. Any hint?

```js
<#list sezione.getSiblings() as sezione>
        "apps" : [
            <#list sezione.applicazione.getSiblings() as app>
            {
                "description" : "${app.descrizione.getData()}" ,
                "name" : "${app.nome.getData()}" ,
                "store_link" : "${app.store_link.getData()}",
            } 
            </#list>
        ],
        "category_title" : "${category_title.getData()}"
</#list>
```

Comment: I don't know Liferay, but certainly it has a stack trace somewhere, like in a log file. That should tell the specifics.

Comment: I guess there could be some name collision problem in this line : `<#list sezione.getSiblings() as sezione>` (and wouldn't be better to navigate the structure using parent-children instead of siblings like `<#list parent.getChildren() as sezione>` ?)